# Unwanted MobileSafari 'Open this page in "App Store"?' dialog

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad, mobile-safari

This seems like a simple fix, but I can't find any information!

Our mobile site in Safari has been sporatically displaying a dialog saying 'Open this page in "App Store"?' with a cancel and open button, both of which dismiss the dialog but don't do anything beyond that.  This dialog doesn't come up all the time, but we have nothing explicitly calling this dialog and want this gone.

We do have a smart banner for our app. We also have 2 buttons in our site source to download/open the app from the page, which links with a specific appstore URL.  I have a feeling this has something to do with this dialog but I don't know what.

Can anyone provide more information about this dialog?  What can we do to prevent its appearance?

If it makes a difference, we're testing this mobile site with an iPad running iOS 7.

I've included this blurred out screen shot to focus on the unwanted dialog.
[image: iPad screen cap of unwanted dialog]

Comment: I saw it with quotes, what I can't understand is why JavaScript code is triggered without any click! Did you try to put something on console?

Comment: This is old, but no.  We wouldn't know where to add any console messages as this dialog seems like an IOS specific dialog and not something that would have originated from our HTML/JS... Really at a loss to what caused this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem for IOS 9.0 and IOS 8.4 and after trying almost everything i found the solution. On click of button which shows this pop-up you must be doing some asynchronous call and on getting the response if you do window.open(someUrl) you will always get this pop-up. You can solve this by making that call sync or get the url even before click on the button and just do window.open with that url. I changed my call to sync this issue is solved.